# docker inspect results into Error: No such object even if image exists

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-repository

I've a docker image pushed to docker registry and it can be pulled with -

```
docker pull <ip>:5000/test:1
```

THis indicates that

the image exists but if it is inspected with -

```
docker inspect <ip>:5000/test:1
```

It results into an error -

```
[]
Error: No such object: <ip>:5000/test:1
```

WHat could be reason of image not being inspected even if it exists?

Answer (score 4):

`docker inspect` command was resulting into failure as I hadn't completed `docker pull` completely. In order to succeed `docker inspect`, you first need to pull image completely.

Comment: How can I pull images inside a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @JinKwon
You can set `alwaysPull True` inside `docker { }`

Comment: Small correction. For `alwaysPull`, true is all lower case. e.g. `alwaysPull true`